# Change all values in a particular column based on one column value or condition in SQL using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

| p_id | m_id | 1_m_ret | 2_m_ret | 3_m_ret | 4_m_ret | 5_m_ret |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p_1 | m_1 | NULL | 1.1 | 3.1 | NULL | 5.5 |
| p_1 | m_2 | 1.23 | 2.5 | 3.6 | 3.3 | 1.5 |
| p_1 | m_3 | 1.10 | 1.6 | 3.5 | 1.8 | 3.2 |

I want to change the values of columns based on p_id to NULL If there's any NULL in the column for the p_id and the result to be like below table:

| p_id | m_id | 1_m_ret | 2_m_ret | 3_m_ret | 4_m_ret | 5_m_ret |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p_1 | m_1 | NULL | 1.1 | 3.1 | NULL | 5.5 |
| p_1 | m_2 | NULL | 2.5 | 3.6 | NULL | 1.5 |
| p_1 | m_3 | NULL | 1.6 | 3.5 | NULL | 3.2 |

I am able to achieve this using custom functions and stored procedure on local. However i need to achieve it using CTE(without function or stored procedure), Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not following the logic in your requirement.  What do you mean by "m_ret of p_id"?  Do you mean set to NULL for rows that have the same p_id if ANY rows with the same p_id have a NULL in that column?  What have you tried so far?  Show us the code you're stuck on.

Comment: @squillman: Yes, That's right. the above one is fake replica of my dataset. I tried using multiple CTEs but its not updating the value to NULL.Thanks

Comment: Do you actually want to update or derive it while the table is being loaded?

Comment: I don't want to update the value on original source. Just want to modify or drive it as table is being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could use a little clarifying but I think I understand it. If there's any NULL in the column for the p_id, you want the column to be NULL everywhere for the p_id. Otherwise, just leave it as is.

So if that's accurate, try this:

```
CASE WHEN FIRST_VALUE(1_m_ret) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY 1_m_ret ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1_m_ret END
```

Comment: SQL Server's analytical functions default to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` when provided with an `ORDER BY`, so that last edit was not required.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70fc6043d5e1d5ff3276a1e88521d539

Comment: I wanted it to be collation-agnostic, just in case. CURRENT ROW wouldn't cut it if NULL was getting collated to the end. It's also less generalizable without that addition. What if I wanted to check for the existence of some random value other than NULL?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be picked up as the first value any way.  The point is fair (NULLS last), but the change doesn't solve it.

Comment: That's a good point, if NULL got collated to the end you would need to switch to LAST_VALUE (and the bounds would be necessary to specify). And it won't solve the random value case without additional tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate way to do this is a conditional windowed count

```sql
CASE WHEN
    COUNT(CASE WHEN 1_m_ret IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id) > 0
  THEN NULL ELSE 1_m_ret END
```